# move guest's shopping cart items to logged in user's basket

Tags: php, laravel, shopping-cart

I'm building a shopping cart with Laravel. The requirement is to allow people to shop for items and add them to cart when proceeded to checkout the customers can either login/ register or continue as a guest. I'm using the guest's session id to store the cart items on a table on the server.

Once the user logs in or creates an account how do popular shopping cart cms scripts apply the guest's items in the basket on to the logged in user's basket? What is the best method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested the shopping cart behaviour on Amazon.

- It will prioritise whatever is in the guest shopping cart to anything stored in the shopping cart in the database.
- If there are any items in the database that are not in the guest shopping cart, it gets added to the merged shopping basket.

So for example:

1. A user's basket in the database contains a smartphone (quantity set to 3 units) and a printer.
2. As a guest, the guest shopping basket contains a smartphone (quantity = 1).
3. The guest logs in
4. Final basket after the shopping carts are merged:

   - Smartphone x 1 (overwrites the one stored in the database)
   - Printer x 1